# What's the most efficient way to pause a CPU-intensive python program?

Tags: python, opencv

I made a neural network (which has unfortunately grown in complexity and become rather CPU intensive) which analyzes screenshots in real-time.

I wish to pause it when I press the letter 'a' and un-pause it when the letter 'a' is pressed again. What is the most efficient way to pause it (without breaking the loop altogether)?

It uses Python OpenCV library, but I don't use cv2.imshow, hence I can't use cv2.Waitkey. I'm running this on Windows 10. Could you please provide example code to your answer? Here's a bit of the code:

```
import cv2
import mss
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

#Creates an endless loop for high-speed image acquisition...
while (True):
    with mss.mss() as sct:
        # Get raw pixels from the screen
        sct_img = sct.grab(sct.monitors[1])

        # Create the Image
        img = Image.frombytes('RGB', sct_img.size, sct_img.bgra, 'raw', 'BGRX')

        #The rest of the neural network goes here...

        #PAUSE statement...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sigwait` from the [`signal` package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.sigwait) in the Python standard library. `sigwait` won't work on Windows.

## Edit

You can do what you want in a platform independent way by using the [`threading` library](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html#condition-objects). Here's a short example program (needs the `py-getch` package if you're running on Linux or Mac):

```
import os
from threading import Thread, Event

if os.name=='nt':
    from msvcrt import getch
elif os.name=='posix':
    from getch import getch
else:
    raise OSError

isRunning = True

def count(event):
    i = 0
    while isRunning:
        event.wait(1)

        if event.isSet() and isRunning:
            event.clear()
            print('Pausing count at %d' % i)
            event.wait()
            print('resuming count')
            event.clear()

        i += 1

def listener(event):
    # in Python, need to mark globals if writing to them
    global isRunning

    while isRunning:
        c = getch()
        if c=='a':
            event.set()
        if c=='e':
            event.set()
            isRunning = False

def main():
    pauseEvent = Event()
    pauseEvent.clear()

    listenerThread = Thread(target=listener, args=(pauseEvent,))

    listenerThread.start()
    count(pauseEvent)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

The above program will run two threads. The main thread will run the `count` function, which adds 1 to a count every second. The other thread runs the `listener` function, which will wait for user input. If type `a`, the `listener` thread will tell the `count` thread to pause and print out the current count. You can type `a` again to resume the count, or you can type `e` to quit.

Comment: I should have specified that I was using Windows earlier. The help file for 'sigwait' states that it is only available on Unix.

Comment: @MonkeyBot2020 You can implement your own (limited) custom signal handling by using the threading library in Python. I've added an example to my answer